# Setting up react-native — Unhelpful error messages

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, nvm

I'm at a bit of a loss in setting up my React-Native project.

The simulator renders that start/loading page, but then fails to render index.ios.js

I'm recieving the following errors in the Xcode console and having no luck in troubleshooting what the problem might:

```
2015-10-05 14:02:40.995 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'Requiring module "ExceptionsManager" which threw an exception'
2015-10-05 14:02:40.998 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'undefined is not an object (evaluating \'require(\'ExceptionsManager\').handleException\')'
2015-10-05 14:02:41.036 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'Requiring module "ExceptionsManager" which threw an exception'
2015-10-05 14:02:41.038 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'undefined is not an object (evaluating \'require(\'ExceptionsManager\').handleException\')'
2015-10-05 14:02:41.067 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'Requiring module "ExceptionsManager" which threw an exception'
2015-10-05 14:02:41.075 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'undefined is not an object (evaluating \'require(\'ExceptionsManager\').handleException\')'
```

In chrome dev tools debugger-ui I get the following errors:

```
Failed to print error:  Requiring module "Promise" which threw an exception —InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:43
Failed to print error:  Requiring module "ExceptionsManager" which threw an exception — InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:43
Failed to print error:  Cannot read property 'handleException' of undefined
```

If these errors are familiar to anyone any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Came across it myself today and it is somewhat cryptic.

Comment: @pbattison Reinstalling react-native worked for me, I'm not sure why but I have to do this every now and then on this particular project.